# How can I change the permission on Ubuntu 20.04 to allow ':' on filename of NTFS external drive

Tags: 20.04, files, ntfs, external-hdd

I was using the Ubuntu 18.04 and everything was fine processing my files that are something like that:
wrfout_d03_2018-01-16_09:00:00.nc

It is an automatic process that a climate model save files and I can't change that.
I have upgraded the Ubuntu to 20.04, and now I'm not allowed to save file anymore with **':'**. So everytime I tried to do it, it shows:
./wrfout_d03_2018-01-16_09:00:00.nc: Invalid argument

Does it have any solution? Why this is possible to do in Ubuntu 18.04 but not on 20.04?

Comment: It's really strange. I have a lot of files with **:** on my external-hdd. After the upgrade to 20.04, I found that I can't have new files. I'm so confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
I add this to the mount command of the external harddrive:

> iocharset=utf8

And now I'm able to save files with ***:*** in filename.

Answer (score 0):

These are characters not supported in file names on ntfs file systems. If you cannot control the file name that the application writes out, then just safe onto an ext4 file system. If needed, you can later batch-rename the files for moving to an ntfs volume if necessary.